# app:collapsedTitleGravity="center" doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

I'm trying to make collapsing title to center by `app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"` in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` but actually `title` not center. I saw  suspicious unnamed-view between `title` and `up button`

1. Is it issue form design support lib?
2. Is there any way to overcome this?

I saw a person who occured like me in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846265/how-to-center-the-title-of-a-collapsingtoolbarlayout).

Here is screen shot

[image: Title is not center suspicious unnamed-view is occured]

This is suspicious unnamed-view [image]

Here is activity_main

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.profile.detail.ProfileDetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/abl_profile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/ctl_profile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="center_horizontal">
           <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<include layout="@layout/content_profile" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In `MainActivity.java`

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

`style.xml` is

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will resolve the issue.

`android:contentInsetStart="0dp" 
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp" 
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp" 
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"`

There is padding reserved so that your title is not next to toolbar icon.

Comment: Try this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62094945/1741586

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute `expandedTitleGravity` that you can use with the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to center the expanded title text. Add this to your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

```
app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
```

Comment: I don't mean expanded title. Issue is  on collapsing state title which is not center.